# How to query multiple level subdocuments in mongodb to get $sum of a field?

Tags: mongodb

Here are some documents from a "Page" collection where I would like to get the sum of field "memberProfile_editAccountProfile"?

```
{
   "_id" : NumberLong(2013083117),
   "count" : 3000,
   "requests" : {
       "consumermx" : {            
       "NFCU" : {
               "memberDashboard_editDashboard" : 24,
               "memberProfile_editAccountProfile" : 1,
               "memberProfile_editPreferencesAssociation" : 1,
               "memberProfile_editPromotionReminder" : 59,
               "memberProfile_savePromotionReminder" : 6,
                        }
                      }
                 }
}

{
   "_id" : NumberLong(2013083118),
   "count" : 3000,
   "requests" : {
       "consumermx" : {            
       "NFCU" : {
               "memberDashboard_editDashboard" : 12,
               "memberProfile_editAccountProfile" : 23,
               "memberProfile_editPreferencesAssociation" : 6,
               "memberProfile_editPromotionReminder" : 21,
               "memberProfile_savePromotionReminder" : 9,
                        }
                      }
                 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
db.Page.aggregate ([{"$group": { "_id":null,
                                 "editAccountProfileSum": {"$sum":"$requests.consumermx.NFCU.memberProfile_editAccountProfile"}}
                     }])
```

Comment: What if you want to filter the count based on a range of timestamp which is the "_id" field?

Comment: You can put a `$match` stage before the `$group`.  The `$match` works like a `find()` query and allows you to pass only those documents that match your criteria to the remainder of the pipeline.  Note that the `_id` in the `$group` has nothing to do with the `_id` in the original documents.  I would recommend using an `ISODate()` value as the timestamp rather than `NumberLong`, as you get more precision from the same space.